# debugging a Javascript function that runs fine on every browser but not if rendered via CefPython

Tags: javascript, cefpython

I am woking on a CEFPython based project in which I am trying to render a webpage having javascript html and css. In this there seems to be some issue with a long javascript function (~980 lines), but while running the same code on the browser it seems to work fine but when I try Implementing the same using CEFPython there seems to be some issue.However all the other JS functions seem to run absolutely fine with CefPython, I am unable to debug the same as there is no error displayed by python and the code runs fine with all the browsers. Kindly suggest how to debug the same?

Comment: 980 lines? unloess this function is an [tag:iife] wrapping some module, then it is too long/it does too much. To your question: no code, no error, no information -> no idea. I would try splitting this thing up into smaller parts and pave this thing in `console.log()`-statements to check wether he runs anything at all/how far he gets.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks For responding the major issue I am facing in the debugging is that It seems to run absolutely fine on any browser with no errors or warning on console however in cefpython it does not, but the other functions do work fine.

Comment: So what, if it works in all **other** browser? That's no argument. *"Works fine everywhere except in the IE"* is my daily bread and butter. You need to find out why it is not working in cefpython.

Comment: Currently latest cefpython embeds Chrome v66 version. So if you're using any js/dom features that appeared in later versions of Chrome it won't work.

Comment: I seem to have solved the issue it was due to "\n" sequences used in javascript for which python showed encoding error while parsing so replaced it with "<br>" and then it seems to work but it would be great if someone could actually explain the reason why it worked after this tweek, am happy that it worked  !!!

Comment: @CzarekTomczak Anything you can suggest about the same ?